# Finding a character outside of markup in JavaScript Regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to find `&` characters via regex which fit a particular rule to avoid formatting for markdown parsing.  The characters should only be matched where they are outside of `<>` tags (e.g. `*<a href="...">*</a>*`), and outside of parenthesis which are not immediately preceded with leading square brackets, such as `*[*]()*`.)

The current version of the regex which works for the first case is:

```
/(\&)(?![^<]*>|[<>]*<\/)/gi
```

And can be viewed [here](https://regex101.com/r/rB9eK1/3).  In this case the third match on the third line should not match.

In addition the test case in the link above is below for the sake of not relying entirely on external sites:

```
& <a href="http://www.google.com?a=b&c=d"> & </a> &
& <a href="http://www.google.com?a=b&c=d"> & </a> &
& ![test & amp](http://www.google.com?a=b&c=d) &
& all the amps on this line should match [ & ] (&) [ &] ( & ) [& ] (& )[&] ( &) &
& <a href="http://www.google.com?a=b&c=d"> & </a> &
& <a href="http://www.google.com?a=b&c=d"> & </a> && <a href="http://www.google.com?a=b&c=d"> & </a> && <a href="http://www.google.com?a=b&c=d"> & </a> &
& <a href="http://www.google.com?a=b&c=d"> & </a> &
```

Comment: One of the best formatted [regex] questions I've seen in years.

Comment: "...should only be matched outside of... and parenthesis where they are not immediately preceded with leading square brackets" - doesn't this mean that that 3rd instance on the 3rd line _should_ match? It's inside parentheses that are immediately preceded by square brackets.

Comment: @ChrisPeacock I revised the wording to make it less imprecise.

Comment: @Tomalak I'm not trying to parse HTML with regex, I'm just looking to escape `&` characters with `&amp;` before they get into the markdown processor I'm using because it doesn't do so itself (it leaves them as `&`, meaning someone could type a code block with `&amp;` in it and get back `&` instead of `&amp;` - not ideal for a code block or really anywhere else given the code-centric content that will be running through it.

Comment: @Tomalak I get that the issue is close, but it's also not.  The desired case is simply "outside of these types of enclosing characters" with an additional "if preceded by" on one of them.  It's nowhere near trying to step to an HTML/XML document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who happens to come across this question, contrary to what someone on this page is suggesting, it is not impossible.  I was able to get it by using lookbehinds after enabling the experimental JavaScript features within the V8 engine.  The following will work in Chrome after going to chrome://flags and checking off `Experimental JavaScript` or running node.js with the --harmony option.

```
/(?<!(?<=\[(.*))\]\(([a-zA-Z0-9\-\.\_\~\:\/\?\#\[\]\@\!\$\&\'\(\)\*\+\,\;\=\%]*))(\&)(?![^<]*>|[<>]*<\/)/gi
```

[Example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lecoder/9fxsshLy/3/).  (must have Harmony enabled within Chrome to view correctly)

Hopefully lookbehinds will make it into the next ECMAScript standard so the other experimental JS stuff won't be needed with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
function processTextNodes(htmlString, callback) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = htmlString;

    var elements = [div];
    var element, child, i;

    while (elements.length) {
        element = elements.shift();
        for (i = 0; i < element.childNodes.length; i++) {
            child = element.childNodes[i];
            if (child.nodeType === element.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                elements.push(child);
            } else if (child.nodeType === element.TEXT_NODE) {
                child.textContent = callback(child);
            }
        }
    }

    return div.innerHTML;
}
```

usage

```
var html = 'hello <h1>This is a heading & a <span>nested value</span></h1> bye!';

processTextNodes(html, function (textNode) {
    return textNode.textContent.toUpperCase();
});
```

gives you

```
"HELLO <h1>THIS IS A HEADING &amp; A <span>NESTED VALUE</span></h1> BYE!"
```

Note how the escaping is done by the browser's HTML parser. Don't try to re-implement that, especially not with regex. The world's most powerful HTML parser that can even deal with any kind of broken input is right at your fingertips. Use it.

If you don't need the "process text node values" part, remove it and the function becomes very short:

```
function fixHTML(htmlString) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = htmlString;    
    return div.innerHTML;
}
```

Comment: This would inject unescaped HTML into the page - a far bigger security concern than preprocessing with regex before it hits a markdown interpreter.  This being aside from the fact my code will be running in node.js so this isn't even an option.

Comment: It would do nothing of that kind. The `div` is never attached to the page. Additionally, all script tags in the HTML string will be stripped. There are HTML DOMs for node, you could run this code pretty much unaltered.

Comment: It still isn't remotely a `JavaScript` solution.

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about. This is Javascript code, it produces the correct result. There are DOM implementations for node, use one of them. You are missing the point that HTML parsing *cannot be done* with regex. That's not the "I don't know how" type of cannot be done, it's the "it's impossible" type of cannot be done.

Comment: As stated before you managed to get the comment removed: This is not a `JavaScript` solution - this relies on a browser dependency and does not work in node.js.  You can as you stated in one of the comments you've since deleted use a node.js module to facilitate this, but it is a huge dependency requirement to do so for something which should be done trivially without adding a module dependency.  By the way, not impossible, I did it and will post how in a moment.

Comment: I have deleted nothing. You have reported the thread, what did you think the moderators would do? Seriously. I have no idea what this passive-aggressive bullshit all the time is about.

Comment: If it's all the time perhaps it's the result of posting irrelevant answers to questions you deride as bad.

Comment: Dude, if you would stop feeling personally offended when I call an idea of yours bad, that would help you look at your code (and mine) more realistically. You have set out to solve your problem with the worst possible tool, and you are not prepared to accept any other view than that regex must be used here. I'm not criticizing *you*, I am criticizing *your approach*, there is a big important difference here.

Comment: If you want to shoot yourself in the foot so bad, go right ahead. Remember to put a little comment with a counter next to your regex that you can increment every time it blows up. I could give you sample input that makes it blow up right now, but I'm too tired. I'm done with this discussion.

Comment: Thanks for the input, it didn't help answer the question at all, would have introduced ridiculous dependencies, bloat, security holes and all the while you called the approach bad.  The approach worked so why you feel the need to continue on I don't know - though given you're stack overflow karma I'd imagine you're all about that, not programming or even an understanding of regex.